# jQuery increment setInverval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, increment

Uh..... I have no idea why this simple code snippet isn't working:

```
function increment() {
     var count = 0;

   alert(count++);

   }

 setInterval(increment, 1000); // test
```

it should display the next number repeatedly, right? It just displays "0". Help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` needs to be a global variable. You are referencing your local variable `count`. Every time the function executes, it gets set to `0`. You are using `count++`, so the value passed to `alert` is `0`, and the incremented value is never used.

To fix this, move the declaration of `count` outside of your function (as per answer by Tim):

```
var count = 0;
function increment() {

   alert(count++);

}

setInterval(increment, 1000); // test
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;
function increment() {

   alert(count++);

   }

 setInterval(increment, 1000); // test
```